# is it possible to disable the ADB debugging authorizations system?

Tags: android, adb, android-9.0-pie, google-pixel

I have rooted pixel device with android pie, I am trying to automate few things with ADB and I am struggling with an authorization issue.

manually it works, I connect to the device through ADB then I approve the auth key manually in the device.

when I am trying to automate this scenario I don't have any option to approve manually this. is there some way to disable this authorization? or maybe do some programmatically/adb manipulation?